# The largest value of $k$ for $\mathbb{Z}^k$ to be embedded in $GL(n,\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, algebraic-groups

This is just a question originated from [This conversation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/863066/898144) (commented by Moishe Kohan). I tried to prove those two assertions but I don't know where to start:

- If H is a free abelian subgroup of $SL(n, \mathbb{Z})$ of rank $k$, you take the Zariski closure $\bar{H} $ of $H$ in $SL(n,\mathbb{R})$; the result is isomorphic to the additive group $\mathbb{R}^k$.
- the group $SL(n,\mathbb{Z})$ has a finite index in $GL(n,\mathbb{Z})$ how can I prove that the ranks of their maximal free abelian subgroups are the same?

If you know any references where i can found this please mention it.

Comment: Sl(n,Z) is the kernel of det : GL(n,Z) -> GL(1,Z) so it is index is equal to the order of GL(1,Z) which is 2

Comment: Yes, I know that  $SL(n,\mathbb{Z})$ has a finite index in $GL(n,\mathbb{Z})$, my question is why the rank of their maximal free abelian subgroups are the same?

Comment: Roughly speaking, here is what is going on.  Take F to be the maximal free abelian subgroup of Sl(n,Z).  It is a free abelian subgroup of Gl(n,Z).  Suppose we have an element x in Gl(n,Z) that commutes with F.  Since Sl(n,Z) has index 2, its square is in Sl(n,Z), thus $x^2\in F$.  Thus $\langle F,x\rangle$ has the same rank as F.

Comment: @user43326 can you please tell me why this is true: Since $Sl(n,Z)$ has index $2$, its square is in $Sl(n,Z)$,

Comment: If $N$ is a subgroup of index 2 in a group $G$ and $x\in G$, then $N$ is normal, $G/N\cong C_2$ and $x^2N = (xN)^2=N$, hence $x^2\in N$

Comment: @MaxHorn How did you conclude or prove that $G/N \cong C_2$? and if we prove that $g^2 \in F$ we can only conclude that $<F,g^2>$ has the same rank as $F$ because $<g^2>$ is a subgroup in $<g>$ .... but we need to prove that $<F,g>$ has the same rank as $F$

Comment: If $N$ has index 2 then it is an easy exercise that it then is normal. And the quotient must of order 2. There is only one isomorphism type of groups of order 2.

Comment: Moreover $\langle F, g^2\rangle$ has index 2 in $\langle F, g\rangle$, so must also be free abelian of the same rank.

Comment: @MaxHorn thanks in advance for your time .... Yes, I know that if $N$ has index $2$ then it is normal in $G$ but can I prove that the quotient is of order 2??
For the second comment, you just use what I am trying to prove as a result to conclude that $<F,g^2>$ has the same rank as $<F,g>$

Comment: How do you defined "$N$ has index 2 in $G$? How do  you define $G/N$?

Comment: A subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^n$ of finite index is again isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^n$ is a basic fact from the theory of finitely generated abelian groups resp. from lattices. There are plenty textbooks discussing this..

Comment: @MaxHorn $N$ has index $2$ in $G$ means that there exist $g_1$, $g_2$ in $G$ such that {$g_1N$,$g_2$} form a partition of $G$ and i defined $G/N$ to be the set of all elemants of the form $gN$ where $g \in G$.

The group $\mathbb{Z}^{n-1}\times {0}$ is normal in $\mathbb{Z}^n$ but it is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^n$.

Comment: Index 2 means there are two cosets. And $G/N$ consists of all cosets. Of which there are two. So the size of $G/N$ is...  And for the second point, every subgroup of an abelian group is normal, that's not the point; the *finite index* bit matters, and in your "example" the index is not finite

Comment: @MaxHorn, Thanks for your time . . . For the second part, we know that $<g^2>$ is a subgroup in $<g>$ and $g^2 \in F$, then $<F,g^2>$ has the same rank as $<F>$ now how I can prove that $<F,g>$ and $F$ have the same rank ?? $ is <g^2>$ and $<g>$ have different generator??

Comment: You started out by assuming $F$ has maximal rank...

Comment: @MaxHorn, Now i get it thank you so much for your time . . . is it true that if we have $H$ a subgroup of finite index $n$ in $G$, we can say that for $g \in G$, $g^n \in H$ ?? can we say that $G/H \cong \mathbb{Z}_n$ ???
because in our example we use the fact that $G/H \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: Yes but only if $H$ is also normal in $G$. Which is automatic for index 2, but not for index $>2$.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't checked this site for a while...  i) in general if you have a surjective homomorphism f:G -> K with Kernel H, then the index of H in G is same as the order of K

Comment: And to be explicit with coset, GL(n,Z) have the matrices with det=1,  and det=-1, and they form the two cosets GL/SL